# Como pegar valor atualizado do input e enviar para outra pagina html

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou pegando os dados de um formulário da seguinte forma:

```
function save(){
    window.localStorage.setItem('nome', $('#nome').val());
    window.localStorage.setItem('sobrenome', $('#sobrenome').val());
    window.localStorage.setItem('email', $('#email').val());
}
function load(){
    $('#nome').val(window.localStorage.getItem('nome'));
    $('#sobrenome').val(window.localStorage.getItem('sobrenome'));
    $('#email').val(window.localStorage.getItem('email'));
}
```

e no html

pag1:

```
<body onload="save()" onunload="save()">
```

na pag2

```
<body onload="load()">
```

O problema é que na segunda pagina os valores não podem ser alterados, teria alguma forma de alterar os valores? e se necessário conseguisse mandar para outra pagina os valores alterados "para uma terceira pagina"?

Comment: Ficou bem confuso de entender Vagner!

Comment: Eu tenho três paginas 
a primeira é um formulário que vai passar as informações para a segunda pagina

a segunda pagina recebe as informações do primeiro formulário com a opção de editar as informações e mandar para a terceira pagina 

mas da maneira que fiz as paginas recebem os dados mas não é possível alterar

Comment: Mas para que então pegar os valores se vc vai alterar eles?

Comment: Isso é só uma opção caso queira alterá-los  se não os dados serão enviados como vieram, serve para ajudar o usuário apenas...

Comment: Entendi, Vagner vc pode mudar o valor do localStorage normalmente, só colocá-lo em uma váriavel e alterar seu valor.

Comment: No caso você teria que criar outro formulário na segunda página para que o usuário possa alterar as informações.

Comment: Consegui resolver obrigado